# in_app_purchase IOS flutter products not fetching

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase, flutter-in-app-purchase

I am able to test my IAP successfully using https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase in the simulator using storekit.

However, when I try to test on my device in sandbox mode, the products I setup in in App Store Connect are not showing.

productDetailResponse.productDetails.isEmpty is indeed empty in sandbox mode.

FYI my developer account with Apple has all agreements signed, and it is "Active" under Paid Apps

Here is my product:

[Products](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnC4E.png)

I have even debugged import 'package:in_app_purchase_storekit/in_app_purchase_storekit.dart'; and not seeing any errors.

StoreKit is also set to none in Xcode.

Does it matter that it is in Drafts?
Does it matter that it is Ready to submit?
If not, then what could the issue be?
There is nothing in the logs giving any clues.

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.